# Is it possible to add a console.log before and after each function in a NodeJS codebase?

Tags: node.js

The idea would be to achieve this without editing the existing functions, neither having to add a wrapper to all of the functions in the codebase.

Ideally, the console.log should only apply to the functions in my codebase and not to for instance node modules functions.

I would like to console log at the beginning the function name and the arguments with which the function is being called and at the end the function name and the return value.

Does anyone know a solution that satisfies this requirements? Maybe with babel?

Comment: You could write a custom AST visitor/transformer that adds `console.log` calls to the start and end of every function body definition. If you're using TypeScript, look into "Custom Transformers". A nice guide for writing those can be found here: https://github.com/itsdouges/typescript-transformer-handbook 

Ultimately the implementation specifics differ per build system, so you'll have to figure out what exactly is required to make it work with the tools you are using.

Comment: I'm not using TypeScript, but I guess a solution might be to just make every .js file a .ts file and then I can add a Custom Transformer? @kwyntes

Comment: Unless you want to switch to TypeScript, you don't have to do that. You can write an AST transformer for plain JavaScript as well, the implementation just depends on the build system you're using. If you haven't decided on a build system yet, I'd personally recommend Parcel, they have a guide on writing an AST transformer in the documentation.

Comment: Actually that is a bit misleading. Build systems such as Parcel themselves don't parse the JS files, so unless something else already does you're not guaranteed to be able to get an AST directly. For parsing plain JavaScript writing a Babel plugin probably makes the most sense (although you could write your own compilation script that parses the JS using a parser of your choice and then walks the AST). I do feel like Babel is a bit outdated since browsers support modern ES features and most people seem to use TypeScript anyway nowadays, but I'm not too sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Babel plugin that should do what you want. Note that for functions *defined* anonymously it will log "<anonymous>" for the function name, regardless of whether they are later assigned to a variable or not, which may or may not be what you want.

I tried to keep the code as simple as possible, so you should be able to tweak it to your own liking.

---

`babel-plugin-autologcalls.mjs`

```js
function insertLogBeforeFunctionBody(
  t,
  node,
  // default to using the arguments keyword
  args = [t.identifier("arguments")]
) {
  // node.body is a BlockStatement
  // we want to append a console.log("CALL [<function name>]", arguments) to the body of that block statement
  node.body.body.unshift(
    t.expressionStatement(
      t.callExpression(t.identifier("console.log"), [
        t.stringLiteral(`CALL [${node.id?.name || "<anonymous>"}]`),
        ...args,
      ])
    )
  );
}

// recursively extract the identifiers from any kind of parameter
function getParameterIdentifiers(param) {
  switch (param.type) {
    case "Identifier":
      return [param];
    case "ArrayPattern":
      return param.elements.flatMap(getParameterIdentifiers);
    case "ObjectPattern":
      return param.properties.flatMap((prop) =>
        getParameterIdentifiers(prop.value)
      );
    case "RestElement":
      return [param.argument];
  }
}

function insertLogBeforeArrowFunctionBody(t, node, scope) {
  // rewrite arrow function of form () => ... to () => { return ... } so we can insert a console.log
  if (node.body.type !== "BlockStatement") {
    node.body = t.blockStatement([
      // will later be replaced by the ReturnStatement visitor
      t.returnStatement(node.body),
    ]);
  }

  insertLogBeforeFunctionBody(
    t,
    node,
    // arrow functions don't support the arguments keyword, so we extract the arguments from the parameters
    node.params.flatMap(getParameterIdentifiers)
  );
}

// recursively find the function the return statement was used in
function getFunctionFromReturnStatement(path) {
  return path.type.match(/^(Arrow)?Function(Declaration|Expression)$/)
    ? path.node
    : getFunctionFromReturnStatement(path.parentPath);
}

function insertLogBeforeReturnStatement(t, path) {
  const retId = path.scope.generateUidIdentifier("ret");

  path.replaceWithMultiple([
    // const <retId> = <returned value>
    // console.log("RETURN [<function name>]", <retId>);
    // return <retId>;
    t.variableDeclaration("const", [
      t.variableDeclarator(retId, path.node.argument),
    ]),
    t.expressionStatement(
      t.callExpression(t.identifier("console.log"), [
        t.stringLiteral(
          `RETURN [${
            getFunctionFromReturnStatement(path).id?.name || "<anonymous>"
          }]`
        ),
        retId,
      ])
    ),
    // add extra __isLogged property to prevent an infinite loop where the replacement return statement gets visited
    { ...t.returnStatement(retId), __isLogged: true },
  ]);
}

export default function ({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      // function <name>() { ... }  (statement)
      FunctionDeclaration({ node }) {
        insertLogBeforeFunctionBody(t, node);
      },
      // function <name?>() { ... }  (expression)
      FunctionExpression({ node }) {
        insertLogBeforeFunctionBody(t, node);
      },
      // () => ... or () => { ... }
      ArrowFunctionExpression({ node, scope }) {
        insertLogBeforeArrowFunctionBody(t, node, scope);
      },
      // return ...
      ReturnStatement(path) {
        if (!path.node.__isLogged) {
          insertLogBeforeReturnStatement(t, path);
        }
      },
    },
  };
}
```

In order to use this, register it in a `babel.config.json` or `.babelrc` file as follows:

```json
{
  "plugins": ["./babel-plugin-autologcalls.mjs"]
}
```

Then compile your code using the command `npx babel <source.js> --out-dir <output directory>` after having installed Babel in your project by running `npm i -D @babel/core @babel/cli`.

(Note that there are different ways of using Babel, so refer to [its documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage) for more options.)

---

Using this plugin, the following code ...

```js
function emptyfn() {}

function normalfn(s) {
  if (s.length > 1) {
    return s;
  }

  return arguments;
}

const anonymousfn = function () {
  return arguments;
};

const arrowfn = (
  _,
  n,
  [expanded],
  {
    _: {
      nested: [fn],
    },
    d,
  }
) => {
  return fn(n + expanded - d);
};

const lambda = (...args) => args;

const exampleargs = [
  "a",
  10,
  [5, 6, 7],
  { _: { nested: [(a) => `(${a})`] }, d: -11 },
];
normalfn(...exampleargs);
anonymousfn(...exampleargs);
arrowfn(...exampleargs);
lambda(...exampleargs);
```

... will be compiled to:

```js
function emptyfn() {
  console.log("CALL [emptyfn]", arguments);
}
function normalfn(s) {
  console.log("CALL [normalfn]", arguments);
  if (s.length > 1) {
    const _ret = s;
    console.log("RETURN [normalfn]", _ret);
    return _ret;
  }
  const _ret2 = arguments;
  console.log("RETURN [normalfn]", _ret2);
  return _ret2;
}
const anonymousfn = function () {
  console.log("CALL [<anonymous>]", arguments);
  const _ret3 = arguments;
  console.log("RETURN [<anonymous>]", _ret3);
  return _ret3;
};
const arrowfn = (_, n, [expanded], {
  _: {
    nested: [fn]
  },
  d
}) => {
  console.log("CALL [<anonymous>]", _, n, expanded, fn, d);
  const _ret4 = fn(n + expanded - d);
  console.log("RETURN [<anonymous>]", _ret4);
  return _ret4;
};
const lambda = (...args) => {
  console.log("CALL [<anonymous>]", args);
  const _ret5 = args;
  console.log("RETURN [<anonymous>]", _ret5);
  return _ret5;
};
const exampleargs = ["a", 10, [5, 6, 7], {
  _: {
    nested: [a => {
      console.log("CALL [<anonymous>]", a);
      const _ret6 = `(${a})`;
      console.log("RETURN [<anonymous>]", _ret6);
      return _ret6;
    }]
  },
  d: -11
}];
normalfn(...exampleargs);
anonymousfn(...exampleargs);
arrowfn(...exampleargs);
lambda(...exampleargs);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Some minor improvements I had to add in order to make the build work in my codebase without errors:
1. Update the "ObjectPattern" case to have "prop.argument || getParameterIdentifiers(prop.value)" in the flatMap
2. Update the "ArrayPattern" case with a .filter(Boolean) in order to handle array destructuring cases such as [, e], where the first element is null
3. Update the getFunctionFromReturnStatement regex to /^(Arrow)?Function(Declaration|Expression)|ObjectMethod$/